# Rufus says that device is in use by Windows but it isn't listed in any Windows utilities

Tags: windows, usb, rufus

So, I was creating a bootable drive of Windows 10 using Rufus when I got some error like "Device is being used by windows blah blah blah" and the process failed.

The device was not listed in Explorer. In Disk Management & Disk Part, it was displayed as No media and 0 bytes. I tried cleaning it through Disk Part, but it failed saying `Virtual Disk Service error:There is no media in the device`. It doesn't show any volumes on the disk. I tried HDD Low Level Format tool, but it too didn't detect my device.

Why is this error occurring? Is there any solution to it?

Comment: Having access to the exact text of the error would be helpful. Can you repeat the process with Rufus and then update the question with that information?

Comment: "I was creating a bootable drive " What kind of drive?

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/1467957/rufus-gets-interrupted-by-explorer-exe-almost-every-time